# Is it possible to prevent Spring WebFlow bindings from resolving query parameters?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, data-binding, spring-webflow-2

I have a simple view-state:

```
<view-state id="loginForm" view="loginView" model="user">
  <binder>
    <binding property="email" />
    <binding property="password" />
  </binder>
  ...
</view-state>
```

And a url *MAY* contain `?email=somebody%40somewhere.com` for other purposes (not this form).  The initial rendering of the view is fine, but upon submit, the value that gets bound to `user.email` is a `List<String>` containing both the value from the form (posted back) *AND* the query parameter value.  This is not only unexpected, but potentially dangerous (*i think*).  Anyway, I would like to prevent the binding of query parameters.  Is there a way to configure this?

Comment: Sounds like the real issue is you need to prevent the url from containing param '?email=somebody%40somewhere.com'. The binder works like a boolean flag either 'email' is bound or not (TRUE | FALSE ).

Comment: Maybe 1 workaround would be since you have ( 2 ) email params that mean different things is to assign different names to the params. Maybe call 1 'login' and the other 'email'

Comment: @Airduster, yeah, i ended up going with different names, but still seems logical that you could force the binder to only bind from `POST` params to prevent this type of incidental collision.

Comment: Glad to hear a workaround. You could make an enhancement request @ the SWF project on their jira page